# Are these 2 definite integral the same? Why?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Are these two definite integrals the same?

> $$\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}\frac{\sin 6\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)}{\sin\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)}dx$$ $$\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}\frac{\sin 6\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)}{\sin\left(x+\frac{π}{4}\right)} d(x+\frac{π}{4})$$

I saw that in my textbook. Someone told me they are but i can’t really get why they are the same

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well it depends. Usually the convention I've seen for the bounds is that $$\int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx = \int_{\min\{g(a),g(b)\}}^{\max\{g(a),g(b)\}}f(x) d(g(x))$$ but this doesn't seem to be a hard and fast rule, it could be written as $a,b$ as well.

Comment: How do you write it from g(a) g(b) to$ \pi/2, 0$

Comment: @Ninad Munshi If both g(a), g(b), and a,b are acceptable but they appear to be a different numbers, won’t it cause some conflicts?

Comment: No, the ambiguity is either clear from context, or the author explicitly writes $x=\cdots$ or $g(x)=\cdots$ in each of the bounds

Comment: Oh, i think i got your mean. Do you mean that for the one with d(x+\pi/4), the integrad (\pi/2) is still talking about the x only instead of (x+pi/2) as a whole so it will still be valid?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $u=x+\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I tried that substitution but it ends up with $int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}$

Comment: @user588102 Do it for both of them.

Comment: Oh, i see what you mean now

Answer (score 1):

Since the integrand of both integrals is same, we only need to look at the differential coefficients. For the first integral, the differential coefficient is $dx$, whereas for the second, it is $d(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$. You can rewrite this as:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x+\frac \pi 4) \cdot dx = dx$$
since $\frac{d}{dx} (x + \frac \pi 4) = 1$.

---

An alternative solution would be to do a substitution. This is slightly lengthier, but if you're still not convinced, for the second integral, let $t = x + \frac \pi 4$. The integral is then
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\frac{\sin(6t)}{\sin t}dt$$
For the first integral, make the same substitution. You'll get the same integral, since $t = x + \frac \pi 4 \implies dt = dx$:
$$\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\frac{\sin(6t)}{\sin t}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x+\frac{\pi}{4} \implies du=d(x+\frac{\pi}{4})=dx$
$$I_1=\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}{\frac{\sin(6u)}{\sin(u)}du}$$
$$I_2=\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}{\frac{\sin(6u)}{\sin(u)}du}$$

Comment: What is the difference between $I_1$ and $I_2$?

Comment: Your first image is $I_1$ and the next $I_2$.  They're both the same

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean